Logarithmic inequality involving $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$

Given the real numbers $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$ all greater than $1$, such that $\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i=10^n$, prove that:
$$\frac{\log_{10}a_1}{(1+\log_{10}a_1)^2}+\frac{\log_{10}a_2}{(1+\log_{10}a_1 + \log_{10}a_2)^2}+...+\frac{\log_{10}a_n}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log_{10}a_i)^2}\le\frac{n}{n+1}$$

My first try was with proof by induction. It did not work. My second attempt goes as follows:
Let`s define the numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, such that $x_1=\log_{10}a_1, x_2=\log_{10}a_2,...,x_n=\log_{10}a_n$. This implies that every number $x_i>0$, where $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ ; and that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=n$, so the inequality becomes: $$\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2}+\frac{x_2}{(1+x_1 +x_2)^2}+...+\frac{x_n}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i)^2}\le\frac{n}{n+1}.$$
$\phantom{2}$
Then I tried to identify another expression for each of the fractions, so that we can work with them. My best guess was that for every $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, $$\frac{x_n}{(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_n)^2}< \frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_n}$$ so that the inequality can be rewritten as: $$\frac{1}{1+x_1}+\frac{1}{1+x_1+x_2}+...+\frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_n}\le\frac{n}{n+1}$$
But now I am stuck. My biggest problem is that the denominators contain multiple values of $x_n$. Is there a way or strategy to handle such problems more efficiently?

Is it provided that $a_i>a_j$ if $i>j$?

No. It is not provided.

Also by $\operatorname{lg}$ do you mean logarithm for base 10?

Yes, logarithm for base 10, and I also edited the problem...I misinterpreted the problem, sorry

The inequality is still true if the condition $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = n$ is dropped. In other words, we have the following result.
Fact 1. Let $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \ge 0$. Then $$\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2}+\frac{x_2}{(1+x_1 +x_2)^2} + \cdots + \frac{x_n}{(1 + x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n)^2} \le \frac{n}{1+n}.$$
Proof of Fact 1.
We use the Mathematical Induction.
When $n = 1$, true.
Assume that the statement is true for $n$ ($n\ge 1$).
For $n + 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2}+\frac{x_2}{(1+x_1 +x_2)^2} + \cdots + \frac{x_{n+1}}{(1 + x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{n+1})^2}\\
 ={}& \frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2} + \frac{1}{1 + x_1}\\
 &\quad 
 \times \left(\frac{y_1}{(1+y_1)^2}+\frac{y_2}{(1+y_1 +y_2)^2} + \cdots + \frac{y_n}{(1 + y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_n)^2}
 \right)\\
 \le{}& \frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2} + \frac{1}{1 + x_1}\cdot\frac{n}{n+1}\\
 \le{}&\frac{(2n+1)^2}{4(n+1)^2}\\
 \le{}& \frac{n+1}{n+2}
\end{align*}
where $y_k = \frac{x_{k+1}}{1 + x_1}, k=1, 2, \cdots, n$, and
we use
$$\frac{(2n+1)^2}{4(n+1)^2}
- \frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2} - \frac{n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{1 + x_1}
= \frac{(2nx_1 + x_1 - 1)^2}{4(n+1)^2(1+x_1)^2}.$$
Thus, the statement is true for $n+1$.
We are done.

I don't quite get this. Shouldn't the inequality via induction look like $\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{x_k}{(1+n+x_k)^2}\le\frac{n+1}{n+2}$, where $k=n+1$?

@fikooo I discard the condition $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = n$.

Would it work the same way using the condition?

@fikooo How do you use the condition in Induction?

@fikooo You can take $n = 4$ to see the Mathematical Induction process.

Like we accept for $n$, that the inequality is true. Proving for $n+1$ would be: $\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2}+...+\frac{x_n}{(1+x_1+...x_n)^2+\frac{x_k}{(1+x_1+...x_n+x_k)^2}\le\frac{n+1}{n+2}$$, where $k=n+1$ Since we have accepted that the inequality is true for n, it can be rewritten as: $\frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{x_k}{(1+n+x_k)^2}\le \frac{n+1}{n+2}$

I have made a comment...not sure if it can be visible. There was somewhere a Latex syntax error, and now I can't edit it for a while.

@fikooo Take $n = 2$ for example.
Assume that $\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2}

\frac{x_2}{(1+x_1+x_2)^2} \le \frac23$
for $x_1 + x_2 = 2$.
We want to prove that
$\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2}
\frac{x_2}{(1+x_1+x_2)^2} + \frac{x_3}{(1+x_1+x_2+x_3)^2}\le \frac34$
for $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3$. Is this your meaning?


Yes...that's how I meant it to be

@fikooo So for $n=3$, you can not use $x_1 + x_2 = 2$, don't have $\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2} + \frac{x_2}{(1+x_1+x_2)^2} \le \frac23$. Right.

Now I see it, I was thinking about that such an assumption would imply that $x_3=1$ in this case. I wanted to solve it using the given condition, because to be honest I am halfway there to understand your solution.

We can not assume $x_3 = 1$, because actually the inductive hypothesis is $\frac{z_1}{(1+z_1)^2} + \frac{z_2}{(1+z_1+z_2)^2} \le \frac23$ for $z_1 + z_2 = 2$, and you want to prove that $\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2} + \frac{x_2}{(1+x_1+x_2)^2} + \frac{x_3}{(1+x_1+x_2+x_3)^2}\le \frac34$ for $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3$.

@fikooo After discard the constraint $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = n$. Using the inductive hypothesis $\frac{z_1}{(1+z_1)^2} + \frac{z_2}{(1+z_1+z_2)^2} \le \frac23$ for $z_1, z_2 \ge 0$, we want to prove that $\frac{x_1}{(1+x_1)^2} + \frac{1}{1 + x_1}\cdot \left(\frac{y_1}{(1+y_1)^2} + \frac{y_2}{(1+y_1+y_2)^2}\right) \le \frac34$. Now, you see we can use the inductive hypothesis via $\frac{y_1}{(1+y_1)^2} + \frac{y_2}{(1+y_1+y_2)^2}$.

The inequality on the last line of your post is false while the original inequality is true. The incorrect inequality sign should reverse. It is easy to see it:
$\dfrac{1}{1+x_1} \ge \dfrac{1}{1+x_1+x_2+....+x_n} = \dfrac{1}{1+n}$. Repeat this for the remaining terms, and add them up ! we have:
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k x_i}\ge\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+n}=\dfrac{n}{1+n}. $

I was thinking about this solution as well, but I missed something...but I don't get it...which inequality's sign should be reversed?

@fikooo: The one on the last line of your post. But the original one is valid. I have seen it somewhere.
